# Showing data in a Pivot Table as a %

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm getting frustrated trying to get the each cell to show itself as a % of the "Total days" in that row, e.g. where it says 51.8 for "Billed Days" on the first row I'd like it to say 85.6% (51.8 / 60.5 * 100= 85.6%).

[Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVpd3.png)

Every time I try to use the "Show total as % of row" option it doesn't work. Same goes with choosing "Show total as % of parent row". Both of these options either return 100% or, their % of the whole territory.

Is what I'm asking possible? As Total Days is a calculation of the pivot table itself, does that mean you can't do calculations in the pivot table based upon it?

Comment: I think it should be okay if you select "Show value as % of Parent Row Total". Please don't forget to Summarize value field by "Sum"

Comment: I take it the column layout mirrors how things are set up in the actual data source? i.e. you have a separate column in the raw data for Total Days, a separate column for Billed Days, etc? If so, you need to unpivot this to get Show Value as % options to work. Also, what version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new calculated field in the Pivot Table, and in the formula type in:

```
    = 'Billed Days'/sum('Total Days')
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
    = sum('Billed Days')/sum('Total Days')
```

I'm assuming that when you say "Total Days is a calculation of the pivot table itself", it is simply a calculated field with a formula of: sum('Total Days')